# Fantasy book from the 70s, 80s, or 90s with a main character who kills a mythic beast with a bow

Tags: story-identification, books

All I can recall about it is:

1. It may have been in a book set based on that world
2. The part I recall is that a protagonist is kicked out of his clan/village for something.
3. The same character killed a 'mythic' beast with a bow. The village has a coming of age ritual of wearing masks in public when become adults and said character was gifted a mask made from a tuft of the killed beast.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Which world is "that world?"  It seems like something is missing before that.  Do you recall the cover art or any character or place names?

Comment: sorry, 'that world' references possible other books from the same place. I don't recall anything else from it

Comment: That loosely sounds like the plot behind a movie called `The Village`, but maybe there is a book based on the movie?